# jquery tabs - link directly to tab

Tags: jquery, tabs, jquery-tabs

I have utilized jquery to add some tab functionality to my website.

I have three tabs, and when a user clicks one jquery gets the href off the clicked tab and displays the respective div (which by default is hidden) whilst hiding the others.

I have taken this approach because as far as I understand, having all the divs there on the page maintains the SEO effects of the content, whilst the tab setup makes it more pleasant to view..

Firstly is this correct?

Secondly - is there anyway with this setup to link directly to a tab?

For example I have a 'Details' (default) tab and a 'Reviews' tab. Is there any way I could access domain.com/link.html#review_1 and have the page show the reviews tab by default instead at the division with id review_1?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yeah jQuery UI tabs are hashable (bookmarkable), for example ->

http://muledesign.com/demo/tabs/default-tabs.html#presentation

See this answer -> [JQuery Tabs and Hyperlinking (help me fix my code, please)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14229132/jquery-tabs-and-hyperlinking-help-me-fix-my-code-please/14236403#14236403)