# Javascript tabs and a direct link to a tab

Tags: javascript, html, css, function, tabs

I have a tab system using HTML, Javascript &css. It works great but on a reload of the page the Tab changes back to first even though `#tabname` is still at end of URL.
The HTML Is

```
  <body onLoad="init()">
    <h1>E-SPL</h1>

    <ul id="tabs">
      <li><a href="#dash" class="selected">Dashboard</a></li>
      <li><a href="#take">Take</a></li>
      <li><a href="#list">List</a></li>
      <li><a href="#sett">Account Settings</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div class="tabContent" id="dash">
</div>
 <div class="tabContent hide" id="take">
</div>
 <div class="tabContent hide" id="list">
</div>
 <div class="tabContent hide" id="sett">
</div>
</body>
```

The javascript Is.
    
        //

```
    var tabLinks = new Array();
    var contentDivs = new Array();

    function init() {
      // Grab the tab links and content divs from the page
      var tabListItems = document.getElementById('tabs').childNodes;
      for ( var i = 0; i < tabListItems.length; i++ ) {
        if ( tabListItems[i].nodeName == "LI" ) {
          var tabLink = getFirstChildWithTagName( tabListItems[i], 'A' );
          var id = getHash( tabLink.getAttribute('href') );
          tabLinks[id] = tabLink;
          contentDivs[id] = document.getElementById( id );
        }
      }

      // Assign onclick events to the tab links, and
      // highlight the first tab
      var i = 0;

      for ( var id in tabLinks ) {
        tabLinks[id].onclick = showTab;
        tabLinks[id].onfocus = function() { this.blur() };
        if ( i == 0 ) tabLinks[id].className = 'selected';
        i++;

      }

      // Hide all content divs except the first
      var i = 0;

      for ( var id in contentDivs ) {
        if ( i != 0 ) contentDivs[id].className = 'tabContent hide';
        i++;
      }
    }

    function showTab() {
      var selectedId = getHash( this.getAttribute('href') );

      // Highlight the selected tab, and dim all others.
      // Also show the selected content div, and hide all others.
      for ( var id in contentDivs ) {
        if ( id == selectedId ) {
          tabLinks[id].className = 'selected';
          contentDivs[id].className = 'tabContent';
        } else {
          tabLinks[id].className = '';
          contentDivs[id].className = 'tabContent hide';
        }
      }

      // Stop the browser following the link
      return false;
    }

    function getFirstChildWithTagName( element, tagName ) {
      for ( var i = 0; i < element.childNodes.length; i++ ) {
        if ( element.childNodes[i].nodeName == tagName ) return element.childNodes[i];
      }
    }
    function getHash( url ) {
      var hashPos = url.lastIndexOf ( '#' );
      return url.substring( hashPos + 1 );
    }
    //]]>
    </script>
```

The Tabs are fully operational but when i refresh with index.php#take in the URL it goes back to the beginning.
I have tried adding

```
if( window.location.hash )
    showTab();
```

into the `init()` fucntion, this did not work. Any ideas?

Comment: It looks like your hash matches your Tab's id for each link, so why not match `:target` in CSS

Comment: Would that effect direct linking?

Comment: I had the same problem last year. See related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3601035/jquery-tabs-how-to-create-a-link-to-a-specific-tab and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14229132/jquery-tabs-and-hyperlinking-help-me-fix-my-code-please

Comment: Thanks, i am abit of a noob. I would like a code example to sort my solution if possible. I have tried numerous things and none of them have worked.